# Why does content affect inline-flex parents' alignment?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple buttons, and some of them may have icons within them.
With no icons, they are perfectly aligned, but soon as I add an icon into a button, the vertical alignment of all the buttons goes off, as can be seen in the stackblitz at the end of this post.

Due to the fact that the buttons are part of a library already in use, I cannot change any styling of the parent container to fix this - any changes will have to be within the actual button component. For the same reason I can't use `display: flex` on the button because all existing usage assumes that it has `inline-flex`.

The stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-html-ezhvs3?file=style.css

How can I keep the buttons aligned and keep the icon vertically centered in the button?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [mre] as a codeblock

Comment: Why isn't the stackblitz acceptable?

Comment: Please read [mre] and [ask]. Also, to save time, just do as someone asks. We're trying our best to help you; this includes answering your question as quick as possible. Also, what library are you using that is preventing you from some potential solutions?

Comment: I'm not using a library, I'm providing this code as part of a library that others are using, so  aggressively changing properties that may affect the surroundings of the actual button would affect all other people using it.

Comment: Ok. Anyways, is there a specific reason you're changing the size of the image through font-size? If not, I suggest you try `transform: scale(50%);`. And, please, edit your post to include an [mre].